# How can I know what s3 bucket serverless is using for deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using `sls deploy` to deploy my infra to AWS. I know it creates a s3 bucket to hold all deployment artifacts but I don't know the s3 bucket name it uses. How can I know the bucket name? I can't find it in the cloudformation either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy with `-v` option:

```
sls deploy -v
```

the bucket name will be provided in the `Stack Outputs` section. For example:

```
Stack Outputs
ServerlessDeploymentBucketName: test-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-15adjo1hvwvkj
```